# How and when to dynamically add columns to a Grid in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls, datatemplate

we are trying to add ColumnDefinition to a Grid in WPF dynamically from code behind. The question is: when do you do that? In the Usercontrol's Loaded event? We have a ListView that utilizes a DataTemplate which in turn uses the Grid. How do you access that Grid instance (the one inside a DataTemplate) from code behind? It does have a x:Name but it is not visible in the UserControl's code.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can walk the logical tree using the [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx), then programatically create column definitions.

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/mikehillberg/archive/2008/05/23/Of-logical-and-visual-trees-in-WPF.aspx) is a good article on using the Visual and Logical trees and how to navigate them effectively.

Comment: Exactly. I usually find a visual element (contained in the Grid) by name and then use the VisualTreeHelper to obtain that element's 'Parent', which is the logical element you're looking for.